# shrinking bootstrap navbar in Rails app on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to shrink a bootstrap navbar in an Rails app.. I want the solution to be similar to the navbar on this page http://www.viegandmaagoe.dk/en/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my navbar isn't shrinking on scroll.

here is the code for the

`app/application/_navbar.html.erb`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Circular</a>-->
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%=link_to "About", root_path(@root, :anchor => "about") %><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Ems", root_path(@root, :anchor => "ems") %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Team", root_path(@root, :anchor => "team") %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Contact", root_path(@root, :anchor => "contact") %></li>
  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Here is the code in the `app/assets/javascript/application.js`

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
 $('nav').addClass('shrink');
 } else {
 $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
 }
});
```

And here is the Css in `app/assets/stylesheets/navbar.scss`

```
nav.navbar{
 background-color:#fff;
 // Animation
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


nav.navbar.shrink {
 min-height: 35px;
}
```

It would be so nice if someone could take a look at this and advise me

thanks in advance

Comment: Create a [mcve] (snippet) of your menu and I will write all required `scss` for the transitions.

Comment: Hi @AndreiGheorghiu here is a fiddle I followed to get the effect I wanted, but it´s not working for me in the Rails app..... http://jsfiddle.net/Filo/m7yww8oa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4g7o1fyj/) you can find the clean `scss` code. The snippet in the answer uses the fully prefixed `css` result (you shouldn't need it if you run your code through either `grunt` or `gulp`.

If it doesn't work for you, perhaps you should create an example showing how your current non-shrinked navbar looks like, so I can see what properties I need to animate in order for the shrink-ing transition to work.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
    body {
  min-height: 150vh; }

  .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1); }
    .navbar-default.shrink .navbar-brand img {
      max-height: 45px; }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-brand {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 15px;   }
      .navbar-brand img {
        max-height: 45px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 15px auto;   }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  line-height: 120px;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: line-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: line-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1); }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      line-height: initial;   }
}
.navbar-default.shrink .navbar-nav > li > a {
  line-height: 45px; }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default.shrink .navbar-nav > li > a {
      line-height: initial;   }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    margin: 20px 8px;   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://www.grouptravelvideos.com/images/client/00954/resources/you%20logo%20here.png" /></a>
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="/about"><span class="sr-only">(current))</span>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/ems">Ems</a></li>
      <li><a href="/team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing `</nav>` and `</div>` tags  at the end of your partial. It will work if you close it:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Circular</a>-->
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%=link_to "About", root_path(@root, :anchor => "about") %><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Ems", root_path(@root, :anchor => "ems") %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Team", root_path(@root, :anchor => "team") %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Contact", root_path(@root, :anchor => "contact") %></li>
  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unless he defines some `scss` for both the extended and shrinked versions and some css transitions, I don't see how it could work. Does Rails app come with some pre-defined CSS?

Comment: I was referring to example he posted. It didn't work, because he didn't have closing </nav> tag. Try yourself.

Comment: I don't use Rails app, so I can't try. If it works, it means this "shrink" effect on menu is bundled in the Rails app, because it's not part of Bootstrap.

Comment: If you are not using rails app, don't judge. If you would like to use it I would kindly suggest you to start here: ( https://www.railstutorial.org/book ) It is a very nice book!! Cheers!!

Comment: I do not judge, Blackcoat. I wanted to help, as CSS transitions happens to be my field of expertise. Thank you for your pointers. If I ever need Rails app, I'll use that link. A Happy New Year!

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry, I thought you were trolling :-) I was referring to this phrase from his question:" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my navbar isn't shrinking on scroll.." Then he posted in comment the example he used from jsfiddle in Rails app. I figured out that he didn't close the </nav> tag, although the example from jsfiddle was working in Rails for sure. Good that you help him to achieve his goal about css transitions! Happy holidays :-)

Comment: You were right about the markup being incomplete in the question. In order to make transitions work I had to insert what was posted into a clean Bootstrap navbar example.